# addEventListener syntax with variable function name part 2

Tags: jquery, addeventlistener

This same question has been asked, but in a different context:

I have two divs:

```
<div id='content'>Click Me!</div>
<div id='Div1'></div>
```

This code works (displays "Function A' when clicking Click Me!):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setUp("1");
});

function setUp(i) {
    $('#content').on( 'mouseup', function( ) {f_A( );} )
}

function f_A() {
    $('#Div1').append(document.createTextNode("Function A"));
}
```

However, what I really want to do in `setUp` is to select one of several functions to call, based on the value of `i`.  Therefore, instead of `function( ) { f_A( );}` I need something like `function( ) { FUNCTION_NAME_DEPENDING_ON_i( );}`.  How would I go about doing that?  (I am using jQuery 1.9.1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your functions in an object (or an array if you are using indexes):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Note: instead of '1', you could pass 'f_A' or similar 
    setUp("1");
});

function setUp(i) {
    $('#content').on( 'mouseup', function( ) {funcs[i]( );} )
}

// Note: instead of '1' you could use readable names as the key: 'f_A' or similar
var funcs = {
    "1": function f_A() {
        $('#Div1').append(document.createTextNode("Function A"));
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/ey5Vk/)

Note: if you want to have the same context in the called function as the event handler use this form:

```
$('#content').on( 'mouseup', function(evt) {funcs[i].call(this, evt);} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i will try to give your answer

**Using switch Statement** // if your value of i is limited to some manageable extent like 4 5
 
you can do this like

```
function setUp(i) {
    $('#content').on( 'mouseup', function( ) {
switch(i){
   case 1: funcs[1]( ); // and so on }}
```

)}